# How to create jar from plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I am writing plugin for intelijj-idea 14. The main idea of this plugin is to compile current module, create jar file and deploy it to my own server. 
How can I create jar file inside plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
BuildArtifactsBeforeRunTaskProvider.setBuildArtifactBeforeRun(project,this,artifact);
```